# Another spammer

Tags: support, spam

https://stackoverflow.com/users/351686/user351686

He keep posting iMovie related posts on all the trilogy sites, even on stackapps 2 times.

I think only IP banning could prevent from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth I flagged his two posts as spam. They clearly are not real questions!

Comment: actually, I have flagged multiple times, looks like he keep creating new accounts.

Comment: That sucks. I think you're right, IP ban is the way to go. It's silly, does he think he's going to win us over this way?

Comment: No. But he can keep it up. I recall one member on SU who just couldn't seem to quit.